# Clear cached results of Active Directory queries at domain controller

Tags: networking, active-directory, ldap, dns, adsi

I am establishing an external trust between 2 Win2003 forests. Then i m retrieving groups names from 2nd forest domain while sitting in the domain of 1st forest. Then, i am removing the trust and doing the query again which is bringing the same output. (this time, it is from cache as forest 2 has become unreachable after the removal of trust).

Can anyone tell how to **clear the cache which store the results of Active Directory queries?**

Is this cache only available on primary domain controller or also on secondary domain controllers?

Note :- I m doing query by writing my own ADSI program.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Removing the Trust If you remove the trust from the local domain only, it still appears from the other domain but generates an error if you attempt to validate it. An administrator from the other domain must remove the trust from that domain as well.

Comment: Removing the trust is clearing the cache and not generating the error. I am able to get the same output even after removing the trust.

Comment: @picrodevosio are you saying this solved the problem?? Also, can you post your code?